# Calculate $f '(i)$ where $f(z)=z^i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with this one

The branch is the defined from where we cut the complex plane at the negative real axis and that $f(1)=1$. This means we have the argument going from $-\pi≤arg z< \pi$, right? What is up with the other statement, that $f(1)=1$ and how do i calculate $f'(z)$?

I have got this far

$z^i = exp[i\, logz]= exp[i(log|z|+i\,argz)]$

Comment: The condition $f(1)=1$ is only there to remove the additive constant $2\pi ik$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Just ignore this and use the expression you have stated. Do you know how to derive an exponential function?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I think i will manage that part, just the chain rule and then its straight forward. I was the f(1)=1 part that confused me.